# Clustering sea waves data in R

Tags: r, validation, cluster-analysis

I have proceed in clustering of storm's energy data using different clustering methods (kmeans, hclust, agnes, funny) in R but even if it is easy to choose the best method for my work, I need a computational (and not theoretical) method to compare and evaluate the methods via their results. Do you believe that there is something?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I remember someone using Dunn index to evaluate clustering algorithms. See http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/clValid/html/dunn.html

Comment: Hi. Maybe it is better to ask your question on Cross Validated, which is the platform for questions concerning machine learning and so on from stack exchange. If you are looking for a package in R for clustering, try the caret package. caret includes a lot of different methods for clustering with standardized wrappers, so it is easier to compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will study carefully the above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question, I learnt that you could compute optimal number of clusters using `eclust` function from `factoextra` package

Using `kmeans` demo from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visual-enhancement-of-clustering-analysis-unsupervised-machine-learning)

```
# Load and scale the dataset
data("USArrests")
DF <- scale(USArrests)

When data is not scaledd the clustering results might not be reliable [example](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140711/why-does-gap-statistic-for-k-means-suggest-one-cluster-even-though-there-are-ob)

library("factoextra")

# Enhanced k-means clustering
res.km <- eclust(DF, "kmeans")


# Gap statistic plot
fviz_gap_stat(res.km$gap_stat)
```

[image]

[image]

**Comparison of Clustering Functions:**

You can use all the available methods and compute the optimal number of clusters with:

```
clusterFuncList = c("kmeans", "pam", "clara", "fanny", "hclust", "agnes" ,"diana")


resultList <- sapply(clusterFuncList,function(x) {

cat("Begin clustering for function:",x,"\n")

#For each clustering function find optimal number of clusters, to disable plotting use graph=FALSE
clustObj = eclust(DF, x,graph=FALSE)

#return optimal number of clusters for each clustering function

cat("End clustering for function:",x,"\n\n\n")

resultDF = data.frame(clustFunc = x, optimalNumbClusters = clustObj$nbclust,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

})

# >resultList
  # clustFunc optimalNumbClusters
# 1    kmeans                   4
# 2       pam                   4
# 3     clara                   5
# 4     fanny                   5
# 5    hclust                   4
# 6     agnes                   4
# 7     diana                   4
```

**Gap Statistic i.e. goodness-of-fit measure:**

The "gap statistic" is used as a measure of goodness-of-fit for clustering algorithms, see [paper](http://www.web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf)

For fixed number of user defined clusters we could compare gap statistic for each clustering algorithm with `clusGap` function from `cluster` package:

```
numbClusters = 5

library(cluster)

clusterFuncFixedK = c("kmeans", "pam", "clara", "fanny")

gapStatList <- do.call(rbind,lapply(clusterFuncFixedK,function(x) {

cat("Begin clustering for function:",x,"\n")

set.seed(42)
#For each clustering function compute  gap statistic

gapStatBoot=clusGap(DF,FUNcluster=get(x),K.max=numbClusters)

gapStatVec= round(gapStatBoot$Tab[,"gap"],3)


gapStat_at_AllClusters = paste(gapStatVec,collapse=",")

gapStat_at_chosenCluster = gapStatVec[numbClusters]

#return gap statistic for each clustering function

cat("End clustering for function:",x,"\n\n\n")

resultDF = data.frame(clustFunc = x, gapStat_at_AllClusters = gapStat_at_AllClusters,gapStat_at_chosenCluster = gapStat_at_chosenCluster, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}))

# >gapStatList
#  clustFunc        gapStat_at_AllClusters gapStat_at_chosenCluster
#1    kmeans  0.184,0.235,0.264,0.233,0.27                    0.270
#2       pam 0.181,0.253,0.274,0.307,0.303                    0.303
#3     clara 0.181,0.253,0.276,0.311,0.315                    0.315
#4     fanny  0.181,0.23,0.313,0.351,0.478                    0.478
```

The table above has gap statistic of each algorithm at each clutser from k=1 to 5. Column 3, `gapStat_at_chosenCluster` has the 
    gap statistic at k = 5 cluster. The lower the statistic the better the partitioning hence,at k = 5 clusters, `kmeans` performs better 
    relative to other algorithms on `USArrests` dataset

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that you suggest another way to make clusters (sth that I have already done). It is also fixed that I need 5 clusters, so I am not looking for the optimal number of clusters. Except if there is a meaning to run this code in order to find what method works better with 5 clusters!